# Highcharts,AJAX and MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

There seems to be a lot of fusion regarding MVC, Ajax and Highcharts so I thought I'd post my approach, it's all very simple and I hope it helps someone.

From a simple controller the returns an array of doubles from a DB to the rendering of the data via an Ajax GET request. The chart used in this example is an irregular series chat.

```
[Authorize]
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    DataClassDataContext _context = new DataClassDataContext();

    // GET: Ajax
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        var series = _context.Tests.Where(t => t.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId() && t.Units > 0).Select(t => t.Units);

        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

```js
<script>
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Blood Glucose Levels'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    month: '%e. %b',
                    year: '%b'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Date'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Level (mmol/L)'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

        });

        function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Ajax/Data',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    chart.addSeries({
                        name: 'level',
                        data: response
                    });


                },
                cache: false
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```